# Formulario de Inicio de sesión está descuadrado

Tags: bug, diseño

El botón de Inicio de sesión está descuadrado. Como una imagen vale más que mil palabras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, el botón de Iniciar sesión está descuadrado y se pone por encima del enlace "más opciones para iniciar sesión".

Lo he probado tanto en `Google Chrome` como `Safari` y en ambos navegadores aparece descuadrado.

Comment: Lo mismo para mí con Google Chrome 49.

Comment: Podríais confirmar que no utilizáis zoom de ningún tipo?

Comment: @MiquelColl no, pero si le doy a zoom (tanto para aumentar como para alejar) el error persiste. Dado que en [so] el texto es muy reducido, veo que no pusieron ningún `div` para separar el texto de _más opciones_ del botón.

Comment: @MiquelColl No, no tengo ningún tipo de zoom. Está la página al 100% y como dice `fedorqui` aunque le de al zoom el error persiste.

Comment: Pasa también en Firefox e IE sobre win7. Luego en casa miro en linux también

Comment: También en linux en Firefox y Chromium. Está ajustado al texto en inglés y al tener literales más largos en español no cuadra bien, es solo cosa de CSS

Comment: @blonfu Sí, realmente es cosa de CSS. Sin embargo, desconozco si hay un sitio para insertar este tipo de bugs así que me pareció interesante ponerlo en meta ya que hay una etiqueta dedicada a ello.

Comment: @fedorqui Desde diciembre ya son muchos meses y he podido comprobar que todavía sigue descuadrado...

Comment: Puestos a hacer sangrar los ojos, mira [This mis-aligned border is going to give me nightmares!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350905/1983854). Una vez lo ves, no puedes dejar de verlo :O

Comment: Me pregunto si algún día arreglaran eso, la verdad siento cierto fastidio cada vez que inicio sesión.

Comment: Francisco. Puedes publicar el código de la vista?